# Optimizing Haskell Function to Apply Rules Correctly and Avoid Duplicate Characters

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I have an assignment that asks us to implement some functions.

We must implement a function `apply :: State -> [Rule] -> State`
where `State` is a String and `Rule` is `data Rule = Rule Char State deriving Show`

This means that we should be able to call the function s.t. `apply "FXRYF" [Rule 'X' "XRYF", Rule 'Y' "FXLY"]` will produce `FXRYFRFXLYF"`.

I have an (insufficient) solution, that is missing something that I can not figure out how to do.

```
type State = String
data Rule = Rule Char State deriving Show 

apply :: State -> [Rule] -> State
apply state rules = concat [if char == c then s else [char] | char <- state, Rule c s <- rules]
```

will produce `FFXRYFXRRYFXLYFF`

The problem is that it applies `else [char]` for every rule in `rules`. Ideally it should only apply `else [char]` at the last rule in `rules`.

What to do?

Comment: It seems like you are supposed to apply one rule after the other. Do not use a list comprehension for that, but recursion or `fold`

Comment: You seem to be trying to do two things at once. You might want to start by defining some auxiliary function: `applySingleRule :: State -> Rule -> State`

Comment: @jpmarinier I don't think this function is useful, since in the problem the second rule doesn't appear to be applied to characters produced by the first rule.  How will you know which characters to apply the second rule to?  Instead maybe write `applyRulesToChar :: Char -> [Rule] -> [Char]`.

Comment: @DavidFletcher Assuming your interpretation is correct, yes but it would have to be more like the flipped version: `applyRulesToChar :: [Rule] -> Char -> [Char]` so we could use something like: `concat (map (applyRulesToChar rules) state)`

Comment: @Bergi I don't think so applying them one after the other is correct; the example input-output pair corresponds to parallel expansion and either order of sequential expansion would incorrectly expand something that came from the output of a previous rule.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out and this is the solution:

```
apply state rules = 
    let ruleTable = [(c, s) | Rule c s <- rules]
    in concat [maybe [char] id (lookup char ruleTable) | char <- state]
```

So if the `lookup` function returns `Nothing` then we concatenate `[char]` and otherwise we return the `s` corresponding to some `c` in `ruleTable`.

Comment: Simpler than `maybe [char] id (…)`: `fromMaybe [char] (…)`

Answer (score 0):

Following from a suggestion of @DavidFletcher in one of the comments, and assuming only the first rule match matters:

```
apply :: State -> [Rule] -> State
apply state rules = concatMap applyRulesToChar state  where
    applyRulesToChar char = let  ss = [s | Rule c s <- rules, c==char]
                            in   if (null ss) then [char] else (head ss)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend splitting out a helper function that applies all your rules to a single character.

```
applyRulesOnce :: [Rule] -> Char -> [Char]
applyRulesOnce rules char = case [s | Rule c s <- rules, c == char] of
    [] -> [c]
    s:_ -> s

applyRules :: [Rule] -> State -> State
applyRules = concatMap . applyRulesOnce
```